# Canvas getContext('2d') error when html is loaded through DNS lookup

Tags: javascript, html, iis, canvas, dns

I am running into an issue with canvas. The getContext('2d') call gives an error in case the html page is loaded through DNS lookup (IIS service). If I replace the server name in the address bar with localhost or the ip-address of the server the canvas is functioning normally.

http://localhost/prm.html?line=004&dev=009 OK

http://SERVER01/prm.html?line=004&dev=009  FAIL

```
    <script language="JavaScript" src="GlobalFunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <SCRIPT language=JavaScript1.2 >

    var sYHistogram = createCanvas( 0 );
    writeText('sYHistogram',sYHistogram);
    fillGraph( xml, 0 );

    function createCanvas( canvasId ) {                             
       var sTable ="<TABLE FRAME=rhs CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0 BGCOLOR=#004990>";
       sTable = sTable + "<TR><TD><canvas id='canvas"+canvasId+"' width='200' height='200' style='background-color:#004990'></canvas></TD>";
       sTable = sTable + "</TR></TABLE>";

       return(sTable);
    }

    function writeText( lLayer,sText ) {
       document.all[lLayer].innerHTML = sText;
    }

    function fillGraph( xml, canvasId ) {
       var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"+canvasId);
       try {
           var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
       } catch (error) {
           alert("error in getContext function "+error);
       }
    }
```

The error I get from this code is: error in getContext function [object Error]

The canvas is first created in the page and later edited / filled. This way I was able to resize the canvas based on the available xml data.

What is the difference between using the server name instead of the localhost / ip-address option?

I found the sollution and it consists of 2 steps.

- I added the following line to my html file before the first script tag

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
  ```
- I changed the Process Model Identity setting for the DefaultAppPool in the IIS server to localService

thanks to the responders for your assistance.

  -

Comment: Can you link us to the actual online page? Or create a [mcve]?

Comment: Open the two URLs in your brower and compare the responses. Also have a look at your webserver logfiles.

Comment: @Chris G. It is not an online page. It is a closed offline system with a server and 1 to 5 clients.